# what exactly is nodeType property javascript xml?

Tags: javascript, xml

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_root

Why it is returning number ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName + "<br>" +
    xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeType;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

some garbage text , some garbage text , some garbage text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why it is returning number ?

Because...that's [how it's defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-111237558):

> `nodeType` of type `unsigned short`, readonly
>
> A code representing the type of the underlying object, as defined above.

...where "defined above" is referring to the [`Node` interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247)'s type constants:

> ```
> // NodeType
> const unsigned short      ELEMENT_NODE                   = 1;
> const unsigned short      ATTRIBUTE_NODE                 = 2;
> const unsigned short      TEXT_NODE                      = 3;
> const unsigned short      CDATA_SECTION_NODE             = 4;
> const unsigned short      ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE          = 5;
> const unsigned short      ENTITY_NODE                    = 6;
> const unsigned short      PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE    = 7;
> const unsigned short      COMMENT_NODE                   = 8;
> const unsigned short      DOCUMENT_NODE                  = 9;
> const unsigned short      DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE             = 10;
> const unsigned short      DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE         = 11;
> const unsigned short      NOTATION_NODE                  = 12;
> ```

Comment: so can we say it's just id number to node?

Comment: @sdenri5: No, it's not an ID. It's a number telling you what type of node it is: An element, a text node, etc.

Comment: in javascript if i do typeof(123) it will return number  , for typeof("hello world") will return string .  so not exactly but its like same if node is of type element it will return 1 , if it is of type attribute it will return 2 , can we say its same like typeof()

Comment: @sdenri5: It's *similar*, yes. `typeof` uses strings to identify the types of things. The DOM uses numbers to identify the types of nodes.

Comment: can you explain this  `xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes.length;` how this has 9 childs                books.xml is on this page : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_access.asp

Comment: @sdenri5: Let's not turn this into a conversation. (But remember that `childNodes` includes text nodes, including ones that are just whitespace.)